# Change part of homepage in other template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I've got a blog with an index-template looking like this:

```
<header class="entry-header">
  <h1 class="entry-title">BLOG</h1>
</header>

<div class="entry-content">
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

I'm including the content itself inside the outlet (single-post, post-lists etc.).
However I'd like to change the content of h1 of the template above according to the current route.

How would you do that?

Comment: Change h1 content, class, atrributes, whole element?

Comment: I want to change the content of the h1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `h1` to application template and use property on `ApplicationController`, which can be set in other routes to desired value. Like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('other');
});

App.OtherRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function() {
    this.controllerFor('application').set('elementContent', '123')
  }
});

App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  elementContent: 'BLOG'
});
```

[Demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wizujozebu/2/edit)
If it's not declared in application template, then you can use property on whatever Controller that is controlling your `index-template` and use `this.controllerFor('controllerControllingIndexTemplate').set('property', 'value')` in any route that should change content of h1. It should always work.

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationController`'s [`currentPath`](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/#toc_get-current-route-name-path) stores the full path of the current route. Therefore within `IndexController` specify that it [`needs`](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) ApplicationController and use its `currentPath` property to populate the `h1.entry-title` content:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  currentPath: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.currentPath'),

  isInPostsRoute: Ember.computed.equal('currentPath', 'posts'),
  isInUsersRoute: Ember.computed.equal('currentPath', 'users'),
  // etc
});
```

`index.hbs`:

```
<header class="entry-header">
  <h1 class="entry-title">
    {{#if isInPostsRoute}}
      Posts
    {{else}}{{#if isInUsersRoute}}
      Users
    {{/if}}{{/if}}
  </h1>
</header>
```

Comment: won't that be a bit bloated if I have 5-10 different values for the h1?